# Compare Enums in SpEL

Tags: java, spring, enums, comparison, spring-el

At Spring's [`@Cacheable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) annotation I want to specify an [`unless`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#unless--) condition.

However my return value is neither a primitive type nor a Java bean, but an Enum.

How can I compare for equality with another Enum in SpEL (*Spring Expression Language*)?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are the two operands? What are you comparing?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis An instance of the Enum and a value of the enum. Like `instance == Enum.CERTAIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
#result == T(fully.qualified.path.to.AnEnum).A_VALUE
```

Reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types):

> You can use the special T operator to specify an instance of
> java.lang.Class (the type).

Comment: it works as well

Answer (score 29):

`#object.someEnumProperty.name() == 'CERTAIN_VALUE'`

would work as well.

Comment: You are right @michaldo. I changed my answer to something that actually works. Wrote this from the top of my head. Sorry for the first bad attempt.

Comment: Now is OK. I cancelled my comment

Comment: This can be lot shorter than the accepted answer, because you do not need to write the whole fully qualified path.

Comment: But you'd have to ensure it always matches the enum variable in case it changes