# How do I apply conditional routing in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

Here in my project I'm using scatter gather pattern where 3 parallel calls are happening. I want to achieve conditional routing i.e., from my gateway the request will come and I need to see that request and by determining the request I need to make sure the flow doesn't go to a particular recipient flow. Actually I've configured my flow to be generic so that gateway accepts a request and trigger the same flow for different requests because for all the requests flow is similar. Now for a request if a particular information is not present inside that request json then I don't want to call a particular recipient flow. Below is the code -

//SpringIntegrationConfiguration

```
 @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                gatherer ->
                    gatherer
                        .releaseLockBeforeSend(true)
                        .releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() == 2))
            .aggregate(lionService.someMethod())
            .to(someMethod2());
  }

  //   flow1
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition ->
        integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                (payload, header) -> {
                  try {
                    return lionService.saveRequest(
                        payload,
                        (String) header.get("dbID"),
                        ((SourceSystem) Objects.requireNonNull(header.get("sourceSystem")))
                            .getSourceSystemCode());
                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
                })
            .nullChannel();
  }

  //  flow2
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition ->
        integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(cdService, "callToaNativeMethod");
  }

  // flow3
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow3() {
    return integrationFlowDefinition ->
        integrationFlowDefinition
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(lionService, "prepareRequest")
            .handle(
                Http.outboundGateway(ServiceURL, restTemplateConfig.restTemplate())
                    .mappedRequestHeaders("Content-Type")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class),
                c -> c.advice(expressionAdvice()));
  }

  @Bean
  public Advice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice =
        new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
    advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("'Failed'");
    advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow success() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow failure() {
    return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
  }
  // flow for someMethod2
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow someMethod2() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(
            Http.outboundGateway(someServiceUrl)
                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                .expectedResponseType(CrResponse.class));
  }
}
```

//Gateway

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface GenericGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input")
  void processRequest(
      @Payload Message lionRequest,
      @Header("dbID") String dbID,
      @Header("sourceSystem") SourceSystem sourceSystem);
}
```

The Payload Message lionRequest is going through gateway and invoking the main flow.

Let's imagine LionRequest looks like -

```
{
     "SCode" : "039",
     "CId":"123456",
     "RequestNumber": "56543457",
     "dbID":"987654345678",
     "someRequestBlock":{
         "message":"Dummy input for dummy service"
     }

}
```

Now

1. if `"someRequestBlock"` is not present inside request body then I want `flow2()` to be skipped and `flow1()` and `flow3()` to be run parallelly.
2. Same for the CatRequest, the request body will be different and I need to make sure that for CatRequest `flow1()` to be skipped and `flow2()` and `flow3()` to be ran parallelly.

Kindly suggest how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `.filter()` at the beginning of each flow.

Or, instead of `.recipientFlow`, use this

```java
/**
 * Adds a recipient channel that will be selected if the the expression evaluates to 'true'.
 * @param channelName the channel name.
 * @param expression the expression.
 * @return the router spec.
 */
public RecipientListRouterSpec recipient(String channelName, Expression expression) {
    ExpressionEvaluatingSelector selector = new ExpressionEvaluatingSelector(expression);
    this.handler.addRecipient(channelName, selector);
    this.componentsToRegister.put(selector, null);
    return _this();
}
```

With the expression being a selector to determine whether or not that recipient will receive the message.

You would then start each sub flow with a named channel.

Comment: See my answer: I'm not sure why `recipientFlow(String expression, IntegrationFlow subFlow)` is missed for you as well...

Comment: I see it now; I was only looking at method signatures in the outline; I was expecting to see `(IntegrationFlow, Expression)` or `(IntegrationFlow, String)` for consistency with the channel variants (selector after recipient).

Comment: Yeah... I chose them by the order from shorter to longer method argument. So, the channel name is definitely shorter than expression. Meanwhile an expression is shorter than `IntegrationFlow` :smile:. Although all of this is ambiguously...

Answer (score 0):

There is this recipient variant for the scatterrer:

```
/**
 * Adds a subflow that will be invoked if the expression evaluates to 'true'.
 * @param expression the expression.
 * @param subFlow the subflow.
 * @return the router spec.
 */
public RecipientListRouterSpec recipientFlow(String expression, IntegrationFlow subFlow) {
```

Such a SpEL expression must return `boolean` and it is performed against the whole message. For your convenience the framework provides a `#jsonPath()` SpEL-function to evaluate your `someRequestBlock` attribute against the `payload`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/spel.html#built-in-spel-functions

```
.recipientFlow("#jsonPath(payload, '$..someRequestBlock.length()') > 1", flow2())
```

Can you explain us how do you miss that option, so we may improve something in the code or docs?

Comment: Sorry I missed the documentation somehow. Sorry if I'm asking basic question but what is the #jsonpath here? In my scenario how do I make sure payload is taken into consideration? When I'm keeping #jsonpath it's throwing error. Which path I've to mention here kindly suggest.

Comment: See the doc in my answer to determine what is `#jsonPath()` and follow the link from to the Jayway JsonPath to see what is that and how it works. You showed a JSON in your question, so I made an assumption that your payload is something what can be treated as JSON. What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry I didn't install the dependency so was getting error.

Comment: Hi @Artem, if my condition is to check if a particular field is not present inside JSON then skip that flow, in that case .length()>1 will work or I can put theField != null ?

Comment: Well, yeah. You are right. We also have a `JsonPropertyAccessor` for SpEL therefore it is indeed OK to do like this: `.recipientFlow("payload.someRequestBlock != null", flow2())`. But that `JsonPropertyAccessor` has to be registered: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/spel.html#spel-property-accessors. The `#jsonPath()` is present there by default  only need to add respective `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path` dependency.

Comment: Hi Artem, really sorry if it's too much to ask. As I said this integration flow is a generic one and being used by 4 requests. Now one field is present in one request body but is not present in other requests. I have to make sure if I'm writing spEl expression the way u showed then it'll fail for other requests  as other requests doesn't have that field by default. And even if that field is not present in the other requests bodies I want the flow not to skip flow2() for other requests. In header I have sourceSystem to distinguish between different requests. Can u pls show me how to

Comment: write spEL for that which can accommodate two conditions i.e., sourceSystem(info will come from header)==LionRequest && someField != null ,only then run flow2() otherwise skip that flow.

Comment: If write that in SpEL is too hard for you, you can move such a prediction logic into some bean method and just call it from that expression: `@myRecipientSelector.test(#root)`. Where the `#root` is the whole `Message`, so you will be able in your method to get access not only to payload to determine that field , but also headers for that system type.

Comment: Hi @Artem, how do I access headers field like payload? It seems to be different than how I'm accessing payload fields?

Comment: `headers.my_header`. I have explained what is the root of evaluation context and it has those getters, respectively.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do headers.sourceSystem == 'ONE', but it's not working. All the time it's coming as false for some reason and skipping the flow. Though I checked in header it's sourceSystem=ONE.

Comment: ,Actually this sourceSystem is an enum. And I sent it to gateway in headers. For all other fields in headers the spEl is working but for sourceSystem is not working. Some string also I sent to the headers there I can use '==' operator and it's working. But only for this header value it's not. Is it because the type in enum? But I think whatever I sent to the header it's delegate as String only right? Then ideally it should work. Kindly suggest.

Comment: even I tried doing-->                                                                                     
 SourceSystem sourceSystemProv = SourceSystem.ONE;  //declared the variable                                                           .recipientFlow("headers.sourceSystem == #sourceSystemProv", flow2()) //used the variable here                                                                                                                        That also didn't work.

Comment: It is not clear what made you think that SpEL deals only with strings and it was not clear that your header is an enum. The SpEL is just a slight extension to Java and does not do any conversions to objects it is evaluated against . See here how to compare with an enum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806298/compare-enums-in-spel. Although I’d suggest to use `name()` from that header enum value to compare against string.

Comment: Okay Artem. Is there a way to write condition inside any flow?  We are using condition in recipientFlow() here but if u see my code I want to write condition likewise in to() as well. Is it possible?

Comment: No, a condition is prerogative of specific components, like this recipient list or `filter()`. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#filter

Comment: So is there a different way to make to() conditional?

Comment: Why don’t add that `filter()` before `to()` or as the first operator in that flow?

Comment: If I do that then -  if the condition doesn't match then that flow is not being executed but for some reason the program is getting stuck there. It's not able to come out of the gateway.

Comment: See `discardChannel` on the filter and `bridge()` to reply back to the gateway.