# SpelParseException:: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'eq(==)'

Tags: java, spring

Spring

Java 8

Here my enum

```
public enum NEStatus {
    Online(0), 
    Offline(1),
    Unknown(2),
}
```

Here snippet:

```
@EventListener(condition = "#sdnStatusEvent.getNeStatus() != null && #sdnStatusEvent.getNeStatus() == T(com.mycompany.myproject.NEStatus).Offline")
public void handleSdnStatusEvent(SdnStatusEvent sdnStatusEvent) {
    LOGGER.info("handleSdnStatusEvent: sdnStatusEvent = {}", sdnStatusEvent);
}
```

And this work just fine.

But I want to skip full package name to my enum.

So I try this:

```
    @EventListener(condition = "#sdnStatusEvent.getNeStatus() != null && #sdnStatusEvent.getNeStatus() == #object.NEStatus.name() == 'Offline'")
    public void handleSdnStatusEvent(SdnStatusEvent sdnStatusEvent) {
        LOGGER.info("handleSdnStatusEvent: sdnStatusEvent = {}", sdnStatusEvent);
    }
```

But I get error:

```
2023-07-05 12:25:34.424 ERROR [ContextLoader:localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'eq(==)'
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:129) ~[spring-expression-4.3.22.RELEASE.jar:4.3.22.RELEASE]
```

Comment: How do you think `#sdnStatusEvent.getNeStatus() == #object.NEStatus.name() == 'Offline'` is gonna be evaluated?

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky I get from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33921193/6813231

Comment: @Alexei No you did not, the expression in the link correctly only has one equals operator, yours has two.

Comment: @Gimby I was post my solution

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution

```
public class SdnStatusEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private NEStatus neStatus;

    public SdnStatusEvent(Object source, NEStatus neStatus) {
        super(source);
        this.neStatus = neStatus;
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        return neStatus == NEStatus.Online;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
@EventListener(condition = "#sdnStatusEvent.getNeStatus() != null && #sdnStatusEvent.isOnline()")
    public void handleSdnStatusEvent(SdnStatusEvent sdnStatusEvent) {
}
```

And now it's work just fine :-)